GeoJSON component not updating with state
I am having the following problem: although the filteredData is being updated, the Map doesnt reflect it.
This is the relevant code for my HOC (which contians the Map component):
const handleFilterChange = useCallback((filtered) => {
    console.log('HOC HandleFilter triggered...');
    setFilteredData(filtered);
  }, [setFilteredData]);

return (
    <div>
      <Nav         
        isComparablesToggled={isComparablesToggled} 
        onComparablesToggle={handleDataToggle}  
        data = {data}
        onFilterChange={handleFilterChange}
      />
      <MapContainer center={[53, 0.5]} zoom={7} style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%' }} zoomControl={false}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />

     
        {filteredData.map((data, idx) => (
          <GeoJSON
            key={idx}
            data={data.geometry} 
            style={{ fillColor: 'green', weight: 2, color: 'green' }}
          />
        ))}
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );

Then inside my Nav:
  useEffect(() => {
    const [minArea, maxArea] = areaRange;
    console.log("orginal", data)
    console.log('Filtering with area range:', minArea, maxArea);
    const filtered = filterDataByArea(data, minArea, maxArea);
    console.log('LOC Filtered Data:', filtered);
    onFilterChange(filtered); //Passes data back to HOC

  }, [areaRange]);

I think the most likely culprit is this part not rendering the polygons correctly, but I honestly have no idea:
{filteredData.map((data, idx) => (
          <GeoJSON
            key={idx}
            data={data.geometry} 
            style={{ fillColor: 'green', weight: 2, color: 'green' }}
          />
        ))}

I have checked the filteredData is being updated onFilterChange with this function, so it appears the handleFilterChange is behaving as expected:
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("FILTERED Data", filteredData);
}, [filteredData]);
``` shows that filteredData has updated correctly just the GeoJSON component doesnt..!

